# Do ASUS motherboards have fan-stop feature?

Tags: motherboard, intel

With Intel's 10th and 11th processor generations, it appears that fan-stop has become a needy feature for those who works at night. While Gigabytes advertise their fan-stop feature on mid-range and even low-end motherboards (take B460, B560s for example), I can not find any specification about the feature on ASUS counter part, they just say `Fan Xpert`, which is confusing to those who haven't used ASUS motherboards beforehand.

URLs for comparision [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B560M-PLUS/) | [Gigabyte](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B560M-DS3H-rev-10)

So my question is may soneone use those mainboards let me know **Does ASUS B and H motherboards for Intel 10-11th CPU have fan-stop feature?**

Comment: What does fan-stop have to do with night time work?  Is it too loud? install a water cooling my unit has silent fans.  Want it even more quiet get a giant heatsink, then there are no moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

Fan Xpert is a fan control software, and fan stop is a feature that makes the fans stop when at idle. You can get the same effect as fan stop by using fan Xpert.